# Problem with retrieving SalesOrders by status on NetSuite using SuiteScript

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

So, i'm building a integration with NetSuite, and i need a SuiteScript that gets all SalesOrders based on a status filter. I was able to create scripts that retrieve based on creation date and SO Number, but for some reason, the one using the Status field does not work, seems like i'm using the wrong field for the filter or something, could you please provide me some examples on how you've done it?

Below is my script for reference:

```js
function SearchOrdersByStatus(status){
    var allSalesOrders = [];
    var salesOrdersIds = [];
    var start = 0;
    var pageSize = 1000;
    var filters = [new nlobjSearchFilter('status', null, 'is', status)];
    var columns = [new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid')];
    var searchResults = nlapiSearchRecord('salesorder', null, filters, columns);

    do {
        if (searchResults.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < searchResults.length; i++) {
                salesOrdersIds.push(searchResults[i].getValue('internalid'));
                var salesOrder = nlapiLoadRecord('salesorder', salesOrdersIds[i]);
                allSalesOrders.push(salesOrder);
            }
            start += pageSize;
        }
    } while (searchResults.length >= pageSize);
    return allSalesOrders;
}
```

Comment: Your script as written won't do what you are hoping. Using `nlapiLoadRecord` consumes  10 units of governance per call so if your script is a Suitelet or Restlet the most transactions you would be able to process like this is 99 (the search costs 10 governance units). 

Also this: `var searchResults = nlapiSearchRecord('salesorder', null, filters, columns);` returns null if there are no results so `if( searchResults && searchResults.length) ` is a better idiom. 

And of course you'd have to put the `var searchResults = ...` inside the do loop.

Answer (score 0):

transactions search status is easiest to get by creating and saving a saved search that filters on the statuses of interest and then listing those statuses by extracting them from the saved searches in the console.

see the second script here: [NetSuite Search formula for items that have no open transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75064348/netsuite-search-formula-for-items-that-have-no-open-transactions/75074257#75074257)

the status values you'll use in the search will look like:`'SalesOrd:A', 'SalesOrd:B'` etc

Comment: Hi @bknights, i don't think i got what you're saying, i'm supposed to create a saved search for all my Sales Orders, and then use the script to load the search, and filter it by the status?